# What OAuth grant type should be used for HTML5/JS applicaiton that doesn't need user authorization?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am developing HTML5/JS application that needs to consume internal APIs. The application is accessed only by internal users. I am trying to figure out which OAuth grant type should be used in this situation

OAuth offers multiple grant types and it seems that our web application consuming APIs falls under multiple scenarios.

1. Application is HTML5/JavaScript  - Candidate for implicit Grant
2. API access shouldn't require User authorization  - client credentials grant
3. Application uses SAML based SSO for user log in. Application should be able to access API's once user logs in using SSO. Ideally, SAML2 OAuth grant type would provide a way to translate SAML token to OAuth and use it to access APIs. Unfortunately, based on how Shibboleth/SAML is configured, full SAML token is not accessible once user logs-in and this grant may not be viable.

What OAuth grant should I be using?

In addition, application needs to pass user identity to API for logging/debugging and auditing purpose. What is the best way to incorporate user identity in above solution?

Thanks,